# Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'Y | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that takes a prop with an enum value:

```
export enum AType {
  some = "SOME",
  word = "WORD",
}
```

`const MyComponent = (arg: AType) => {}`

but when I call this:

`<MyComponent arg={arg2} />`

arg2 has the following type:

```
export enum BType {
  other = "OTHER",
  word = "WORD",
}
```

So the types overlap but are not exactly the same. how can this be solved in typescript?

I've tried using `Pick<Btype, "word">` but it doesn't work

Comment: Why are you doing this if you know it is unsound?

Comment: A component with dynamic props? Why? Why not just to make `word` a required prop and the rest optional?

Comment: @caTS I'm reusing a component that requires that type but I now want to expand it. Should I use generics?

Comment: `const MyComponent = ({arg}: { arg: AType}) => {}` would make more sense

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that typescript considers both Enums as separate types and therefore they don't overlap each other enough.
You have to use an intermediate type like

```
export type CType = BType & AType;
```

Since enums are basically objects, you might also want to consider another approach using Records (which btw looks cleaner imo):

```js
export type AType = Record<'word' | 'other', string>;
export type BType = Record<'string', string> & AType; // Easily extendable


const a: Partial<BType> = {
  word: 'word',
  string: 'other string',
};
```

Hope this helps.